# vba custom auto filter with AND condition

Tags: excel, vba

Please guide me as to how to use filter find function in vba. I want to find all the rows which should contain "Mumbai" AND "Delhi".
I used below coding but able to put only on condition.

```
If Not ws1.AutoFilterMode Then
ws1.Range("A1").AutoFilter _
field:=1, Criteria1:="Mumbai", Operator:=xlFilterValues
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

This will filter to rows which contain *either* value Mumbai or Delhi, using the wildcard `*` to include any rows which might contain these values along with other values, e.g., it would include a row where cell value is `Mumbai, India`, etc.

```
ws1.Range("A1").AutoFilter _
    field:=1, _
    Criteria1:="=*Delhi*", _
    Operator:=xlOr, _
    Criteria2:="=*Mumbai*"
```

This is a stricter filter, if you need the filtered cells to contain BOTH Mumbai AND Delhi, then this might work using the `*` wildcard:

```
ws1.Range("A1").AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:="=*Mumbai*Delhi*", _
    Operator:=xlOr, _
    Criteria2:="=*Delhi*Mumbai*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an array for criteria:

```
ws1.Range("A1").Autofilter _
    Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=Array("Mumbai","Delhi"), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```